# Hibernate mapping on non-unique column one to Many Mapping

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have two tables

```
Person
   id --> PK
   name
   media_id

Media
  id --> PK
  media_id
  other_details
```

The Media.Media_id will have duplicate values

now I want to load all media records into person having the given media id

```
public class Person{

    @Id
    private id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany  (**Want to map using MEDIA ID**)
    private List<Media> media= new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Person to Media is unidirectional, Want to know how to do this mapping

Comment: So Person and Media is one to many ? And Media.media_id should be media.person_id ? Is it a typo ? If not , it is very odds as Media has two column , one is called id and other is called media_id.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a oneToMany Relationship. You can use @Formula, like this

```
public class Person{

@Id
private id;

private String name;

private int media_Id // Add a mediaId field to refer to it in the formula

@Transient
@Formula("SELECT * FROM MEDIA WHERE MEDIA_ID = media_Id")
private List<Media> media= new ArrayList<>();
```

}

Comment: getting error , org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: PLAYER, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Formula( SELECT * FROM MEDIA WHERE MEDIA_ID = MEDIA_ID )]

Comment: `@OneToMany
 @Formula("SELECT * FROM MEDIA WHERE MEDIA_ID = MEDIA_ID")
 private List<Media> media= new ArrayList<Media>();`

Comment: If '@OneToMany' fixed the issue, I guess you have a middle table Person_Media. I tried a similar case, but did not want to store the person's assigned Medias in a DB, so I added '@Transient' on the media list. That fixed the exception.